# How to change bash prompt?

Tags: linux, bash, prompt

I'd like to change my bash prompt when I login. But even after I change .bashrc and re-login, it still prompts the old one. What goes wrong please?

I want to get `[\u@\h \W]\$`
but I get `\s-\v\$` for some reasons, and I don't know where it was configured.

This account is not the root, however I have root permissions if necessary

This is what I get:

```
-bash-3.2$ cat .bashrc
PS1='[\u@\h \W]\$'
-bash-3.2$ echo $PS1
\s-\v\$
-bash-3.2$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your shell is an interactive login shell, thus it does not read `~/.bashrc` but `~/.bash_profile` instead:

```
   When  bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-inter‐
   active shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes  com‐
   mands  from  the file /etc/profile, if that file exists.  After reading
   that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile,
   in  that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that
   exists and is readable.  The --noprofile option may be  used  when  the
   shell is started to inhibit this behavior.
```

The quick and dirty fix might be just to symlink `~/.bashrc` to `~/.bash_profile` or vice versa. This possible breaks something with non-interactive shells, e.g. commands run remotely through SSH, so think twice.

See section "INVOCATION" in `man bash` for more details.

Comment: I would rather source `.bashrc` from the profile.